# QBASIC adding a parameter to a SHELL

Tags: shell, qbasic

Using QBASIC: Performing SHELL action: SHELL TMP$ (where TMP$ = C:\test1.exe) but need to pass 1 parameter (a File name) to the test1.exe...jnh999

Comment: You may want ot have a look at the [SHELL command page of the QB64 wiki](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/SHELL) including examples.

Comment: The `SHELL` statement accepts a single string as its argument, so just use string concatenation to add a space and the desired parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to use SHELL in BASIC:

```
REM sample to call shell
PRINT "Enter command";: INPUT Cmd$ ' could be C:\test1.exe
PRINT "Enter parameter";: INPUT Param$ ' could be your filename
ShellStatement$ = Cmd$ + " " + Param$
SHELL ShellStatement$
END
```